# Android show facebook avatar to imageview

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-imageview

i try to show facebook avatar in my imageview .i use facebook graph api.i googled  and i found one example.,but when i run program i can't show facebook avatar in imageview
this is a my source

```
new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                img_value = new URL(
                        "http://graph.facebook.com/634179743325545/picture?type=large");
                Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
                user_img.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

what am i doing wrong ? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: Are you getting any crash? Any exception? Or just the ImageView is not able to host the avatar?

Comment: yes  just imageview is not able to host avatar

Comment: are you trying to set the image from a background thread?

Comment: no i changed my code .now i use Asynctask  ,but result is nothink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `AsyncTask`

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        img_value = new URL(
                    "http://graph.facebook.com/634179743325545/picture?type=large");
        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value
                    .openConnection().getInputStream());
        return null;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
         user_img.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes. mIcon1 is a Bitmap.

Comment: problem solved. problem was http. now i use https and working perfect

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to use Facebook's `ProfilePictureView`?

It is intended to be used to insert the logged user's profile picture so basically what you want to do if I understand it well.

There is an example on how to use it in [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize).

Answer (score 1):

This is Working Code

```
public static String getUrlFacebookUserAvatar(String name_or_idUser )
{
String address = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+name_or_idUser+"/picture";
URL url;
String newLocation = null;
try {
    url = new URL(address);
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false); //Do _not_ follow redirects!
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    newLocation = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return newLocation;
}


private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
     } 
    }
```

and call this method

```
    imgurl=getUrlFacebookUserAvatar("http://graph.facebook.com/100000351746269/picture?type=large");


                new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_mainpage_profile))
                .execute(imgurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I never was able to get the profile image with a HTTP request, I used the built in Request to do it like this

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture,cover"); //only field you need it picture
Request r = Request.newMeRequest(fbSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

        String url = getProfileUrl(response);
        InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    }
 });
r.setParameters(b);
r.executeAndWait();

private String getProfileUrl(Response response){
    try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
        JSONObject JOSource = obj.optJSONObject("picture");
        JSONObject data = JOSource.getJSONObject("data");
        return data.getString("url");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

you suply the bundle with the fields you want and the picture field returns JSON with the image url in it and then you just decode the stream